# regex unique match only multiple lines

Tags: java, regex, pcre

As the title suggests I'm trying to write some Regex for a DLP requirement. In the UK all standard number formatting seems to go out the window and we have numbers that look like the below:

```
01111 111111
01111111111
020 2222 2222
020 22222222
0800 111 1111
0800 1111111
```

By the time you add the international symbol to this and you end up with either
0044 or +44 to each of these, it is getting very messy. I've wrote some regex that is giving me hits for most of these definitions that bit is fine. But the problem I'm having when using a site like regexr.com to test is that I want to be able to get unique results across the entire document being scanned.

My intention is to use this for DLP within our email platform to scan documents and email contents. I'm setting it to hold an email after x amount of matches but currently if it's on a new line then it's a match, even when I specify multiline (maybe I misunderstand how multiline works).

This is my current regex:

```
/(\+[0-9]{7,12}|\b[0-9]{7,12}|[0-9]{3,5} [0-9]{5,9}|\+[0-9]{3,6} [0-9]{5,9}|\+[0-9]{1,4} [0-9]{3,6} [0-9]{4,9}|\+[0-9]{1,4} [0-9]{6,13})(?!.*\1)/gm
```

I'm trying to use this to only give me the last occurance of each example to try and make sure these are unique matches, my requirement for this is that people have email signatures, some with telephone, fax and mobile numbers, that means per email in the chain that could be three numbers. Within a few emails we've already triggered a DLP rule and we'd be holding emails unnecessarily.

Hopefully I've made myself clear on what I'm trying to achieve and I don't feel like I'm too far off my requirement here. Can any Regex gurus point out where I'm going wrong?

Mimecast is my processing engine for this and that supports java/perl regex.

An example email I'd want to match is:

```
Data Leak Email
01111 111111
01111 111112
01111 111113
01111 111114
01111 111115
01111 111116
01111 111117
01111 111118
01111 111119
01111 111110
```

But an email I wouldn't want to flag is:

```
Hi,
Text
Signature 01111 111111
Hi, Text Signature 01111 111111
Hi, Text Signature 01111 111112
Hi, Text Signature 01111 111111
Hi, Text Signature 01111 111112
Hi, Text Signature 01111 111111
Hi, Text Signature 01111 111112
Hi, Text Signature 01111 111111
Hi, Text Signature 01111 111112
Hi, Text Signature 01111 111111
```

As the example at the top has multiple unique numbers within it that highlights a high probability of a contact database leak. The bottom one is an email conversation between two people with reoccuring numbers, so whilst yes the numbers would flag, they would only be counted once. So if I had the amount of numbers to trigger the rule to be 10, they'd be 8 short on the bottom email, but enough to trigger on the top email.

Thanks,

Comment: Is this in Perl, or in Java, where you can accept a fragment of code, or do you just want a regex pattern?

Comment: Data Loss Prevention? Digital Light Processing? I realise that since I didn’t understand immediately, I’m probably not the right person to help you; but if you’d satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: @ Ole V.V. Data Loss prevention :)

Comment: @simbabque it's just a regex pattern I'm using in Mimecast they just said it supports perl or Java regex patterns, that's all the information they've given me unfortunately!

Comment: Actually Perl regexes are more capable than Java

Comment: I found https://community.mimecast.com/docs/DOC-1613, which says it's all Java, but it doesn't mention PCRE. It does mention something called _perlregex_, which might be PCRE.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and add an example email that you would want to match, and one where you would not want it to match?

Comment: Hi, I've just added examples @simbabque

Comment: Ah. Now it makes sense. But I think maybe a single regex is not what you should go for. Is there a way to write some kind of simple plugin for this thing?

Comment: @simbabque unfortunately there isn't, I can filter my search scope to only search attachments for example however then a simple workaround would just be to paste details within the message content.